# ECHO not showing in HTML from PHP

Tags: php, html

For some reason the h1 only says Welcome to Arma 3 Life Highway Patrol's

Any ideas?

```
<?php

//This file will contain the page name and the credits!

function thisPage($page){
    if ($page == 'sops.php'){
        $Npage = 'SOPs';
                return $Npage;

    }elseif ($page == 'changelog.php'){
        $Npage = 'Website Changelog';
                return $Npage;

    }elseif ($page == 'ftodocuments.php'){
        $Npage = 'FTO Documents';
                return $Npage;

    }elseif ($page == 'index.php'){
        $Npage = 'Homepage';
                return $Npage;

    }elseif ($page == 'login.php'){
        $Npage = 'FTO Login Page';
                return $Npage;

    }elseif ($page == 'socialstuff.php'){
        $NPage = 'Social Stuff';
                return $Npage;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
?>

<?php

$findPage = (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
$thisPageName =  thisPage($findPage);

?>
<h1>Welcome to the Arma 3 Life Highway Patrol's <?php echo $thisPageName ?></h1>
<p> Website created by Austin Sharp and assisted by Greyson Henley.</p>
```

Comment: Semi colon is missing.

Comment: nothing shows up because your function returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is your variables. You have two different variables:

```
 $NPage = 'Social Stuff';
 return $Npage;
```

`$NPage` and `$Npage` they do not match.

Comment: That is just a small typo in $page == 'socialstuff.php' condition. Its not there in every condition.

Comment: its not a small typo. if this condition is met, then no output will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `$findPage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);`

It will give the filename and print the proper output.

Comment: "try this" is not a good answer. explain why this may work

Comment: @CodeGodie:- It will work because I just checked it. So may be try word is not exactly the word I should use but there are other solutions so thats why I said try using it and if you like it then keep it.

Comment: thanks for fixing the "try this" answer. it looks better now

Comment: please explain what is the difference between using `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` and `basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])`. Why is he wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just tested the code on MAMP and it worked as it should (saved the file as index.php). What server are you testing this on?

Shot in the dark, but try changing $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_SELF'].

Maybe you could try phpinfo() to see if global php variables are empty.